# How can I make the Neovim terminal run the current file in Python?

Tags: neovim

I know there'a probably a plugin for that, but since Neovim has a built-in terminal I wanna use it. I just want to bind a key that runs the current file in Python 3. I tried using @% and %, but the shell does not recognize these variables. I think the best way would be to export the current file path as an environment variable, and make use it on the terminal. How can I do that?

Comment: do `:term %` or `:term python %` not work?

Answer (score 4):

I am myself pretty new to vim in general, but I guess you can easily do this. Here is my version of it, which will create a horizontal split, create a terminal buffer and then run the current python file in it and then you can create a another mapping which can close the terminal buffer for you.

```
nnoremap <C-R> :sp <CR> :term python % <CR>
nnoremap <C-W> :bd!<CR>
```

Comment: I thought that `<C-R>` and `<C-W>` respectively differentiates from `<C-r>` and `<C-w>` by a Shift key, but they don't. This solution, without modification, shadows some crucial key bindings.

Comment: @UtkanGezer can you please clarify what you mean by this? Are there system key bindings (for <C-R> and <C-W>) that you are referring to? If not, then wouldn't this solution (suggested by @peterh) be okay?

Comment: @Vishal I might have said that because `<C-r>` is the default key binding to *redo what has been undone*, and it seems (according to my old comment) that `<C-R>` refers to the same key combination, therefore shadowing that default and crucial function when rebound. It's been a long time, and I don't remember what exactly my motivation was back then, but this might be it.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for me:

```
" Create a function to open a neovim terminal in a small split window and run python 
function! Termpy()
  exec winheight(0)/4."split" | terminal python3 %
endfunction
```

Then use the solution above to map it to your prefered key combination:

```
" Press CTRL+R to run python script into separate term window 
nnoremap <C-R> :call Termpy() <CR>
```

Other cool things you can do is:

Use a command like :Pyrun

```
command Pyrun execute ":w<CR>:vert ter python3 "%"<CR>"
```

Use leader + p to save and run the script

```
map <leader>p :w<CR>:!python3 %<CR>
```

python2 and python3 are different,so change it for your projects or you can create different functions

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Thanks for spreading the knowledge

Answer (score 0):

It seems others have missed the fact that your workflow is to have a persistent terminal already open below your file, and you want to access the filename from inside your terminal.

I wrote a plugin that handles this by jumping to the regular file, grabbing the filename, and jumping back. In case you don't want to install it, I post the relevant script contents so you can copy that into your vimrc. Finally, a third way is in line with what you suggest, setting the filename every time you visit a buffer, so that it is already ready when you need it.

### Method 1: Install and use vim-termhere

With [vim-termhere](https://github.com/TamaMcGlinn/vim-termhere) installed, a binding such as the one suggested in the readme in your vimrc, and a split terminal below your code active in normal mode, you can do `<leader>cf` to paste the filename relative to the working dir*, or `<leader>cF` to paste the full filename.

*the working dir is not necessarily the same as the terminal's directory. To synchronise either way, you can use [vim-dirhere](https://github.com/TamaMcGlinn/vim-dirhere). With the readme's suggested bindings, `<leader>qq` in normal mode with the cursor on a terminal status line (`username@hostname:~/some/dir $` ) will set the working dir to `~/some/dir`.

If anything fails, please open an issue on the relevant plugin.

### Method 2: Copy some vimscript

If you don't want to install plugins, you can instead copy this and then use `<leader>cf` and `<leader>cF`:

```
function! termhere#JumpToTerminalBuffer() abort
  if &buftype ==# 'terminal'
    return
  endif
  let l:first_window_number = winnr()
  while v:true
    execute "wincmd W"
    if &buftype ==# 'terminal'
      return
    endif
    if winnr() == l:first_window_number
      break
    endif
  endwhile
  throw "Unable to find terminal window in current tab"
endfunction

function! termhere#JumpToNormalBuffer() abort
  if &buftype !=# 'terminal'
    return
  endif
  let l:first_window_number = winnr()
  while v:true
    execute "wincmd W"
    if &buftype !=# 'terminal'
      return
    endif
    if winnr() == l:first_window_number
      break
    endif
  endwhile
  throw "Unable to find non-terminal window in current tab to copy filename from"
endfunction

function! termhere#UseAbsoluteFilenameInTermBelow(prefix, ...) abort
  if &buftype ==# 'terminal'
    call termhere#JumpToNormalBuffer()
  endif
  let l:postfix = get(a:, 1, '')
  let l:filename = expand('%:p')
  call termhere#JumpToTerminalBuffer()
  call feedkeys('a' . a:prefix . l:filename . l:postfix)
endfunction

function! termhere#UseRelativeFilenameInTermBelow(prefix, ...) abort
  if &buftype ==# 'terminal'
    call termhere#JumpToNormalBuffer()
  endif
  let l:postfix = get(a:, 1, '')
  let l:filename = bufname('%')
  call termhere#JumpToTerminalBuffer()
  call feedkeys('a' . a:prefix . l:filename . l:postfix)
endfunction

nnoremap <Leader>cf :call termhere#UseRelativeFilenameInTermBelow('')<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>cF :call termhere#UseAbsoluteFilenameInTermBelow('')<CR>
```

### Method 3: keeping track of the last filename

Although your suggestion to set an environment variable is not necessary, it is possible, and perhaps using a global may be better if you have some other setup than 'a single terminal below a single file':

First, ensure that g:last_regular_file_buffer has the last regular file name in it:

```
function! UpdateLastFile() abort
  if &buftype ==# 'terminal' || bufname('%') ==# ''
    return
  endif
  let g:last_regular_file_buffer = bufname('%')
endfunction

augroup LastRegularFileBuffer
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter * call UpdateLastFile()
augroup END
```

Next, let's set up a keybinding to insert the filename.

```
function! InsertLastFilename() abort
  call feedkeys('a ' . g:last_regular_file_buffer)
endfunction

tnoremap <C-f> <c-\><c-n>:call InsertLastFilename()<CR>
```

Actually using an environment variable instead of a global, while possible, won't work the way you'd expect because a terminal external to neovim will need to be restarted to see changes to the global environment. If necessary, an external terminal can ask the current neovim instance for a value, but that is a whole different question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [code_runner](https://github.com/CRAG666/code_runner.nvim) plugin.

It is very good and the docs is good too.